# How to switch active windows, in the command line, on OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, window, switch-statement

I see a lot of keyboard options mentioned in earlier questions, but I am looking for something I can put in a CLI PHP program on OS X. In my code I view each jpg with Preview within a loop, but after each photo is opened I would like to immediately, programmatically return control (make active) to my terminal window **without any keystrokes needed** for the switch. Because the rest of code needs input after the photo is presented.

Code snippet:

```
<?php
system("stty cbreak");

// View the jpg images one at a time
$files = glob("images/*.jpg");
foreach($files as $jpg){
//  View jpg photo in Preview window, which makes Preview the active window
$cmd = "open $jpg";
exec($cmd);

// Return to terminal window(terminal app?) somehow as active window
// Other code executing in terminal window that requires user input, etc.

?>
```

Comment: I have tried starting "open image.jpg" in the background with "&". That still left the Preview window as the active window.